# Xcode 8 Simulator crash

Tags: ios-simulator, xcode8, ios10

I recently downloaded the Xcode 8 beta. When I try to open the simulator, it gets stuck on the black Apple screen and I get a crash message for "SpringBoard".

Any ideas? I'm happy to edit if I left out anything.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue that is mentioned in the release notes and is related to issues in the download and install process.  If you don't follow the installation instructions exactly, you can trip over this issue.

The workaround is rather straight forward:

1. Using Finder, copy (**DON'T MOVE**) Xcode-beta.app from /Applications to ~/Desktop
2. Delete /Applications/Xcode-beta.app
3. Move Xcode-beta.app from Desktop back to /Applications

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem which, with a bit of googling, I managed to solve as it happened with the Xcode 6 Betas too. First of all, make sure that your Xcode-Beta.app is in the Application folder of your computer. Then go Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations. In "Command Line Tools" you will probably find that you have Xcode 7 selected. This is a problem that occurs with having 2 Xcode versions installed. Change it to Xcode 8.

[image: Select Xcode 8]

After this, the simulators were still broken for me, so I went to Xcode -> Window -> Devices and delete all of the simulators. Then try a full reboot of your computer. Reopen the devices page and add in the simulators that you would like, and then right click on the Xcode app in your dock, and go "Open Developer Tool -> Simulator". Check that it now boots correctly. If its working so far, then you should be good to run your application. Otherwise try yet another reboot, just to make sure Xcode is refreshed.

Hopefully this solves your problem like it did mine, let me know if not.

Answer (score 0):

**SpringBoard failed to launch application with error: 0**

[image]

If you get above issue make your simulator active window and follow step showed below in picture..

**Note : It will delete all app from simulator..**

[image]

Comment: @ghostpotato : do you get SpringBoard failed to launch application with error: 0?