# Xcode 8 : The request to open bundle-id failed. SpringBoard was unable to service the request

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, xcode8, ios10, springboard

I’m trying to run app on iPhone 7 Plus simulator (using Xcode 8.0) but fails by prompting an alert `“The request to open bundle-id failed. SpringBoard was unable to service the request.”`

[image: Screenshot 1]

I’m getting this *frequently (two times in three builds)*. The only fix I found was to `Quit Xcode and Simulator and rebuild app (not worthy).`

Any other fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below work around from [thread here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/48540):

> Issue is the installation issue whereby your install is getting
>   AppTranslocated for some reason.  Some have reported this if they run
>   Xcode-beta.app right out of Downloads, but others have seen it even
>   following our reccomended installation instructions.  We're still
>   investigating in order to provide an update to the release note.

To fix it:

1. Copy-paste `Xcode-beta.app` from Applications folder to somewhere else, e.g. Documents folder.
2. Delete `Xcode-beta.app` from Applications folder.
3. Move `Xcode-beta.app` from Documents to Applications folder again.

Also check [this stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37890673/xcode-8-simulator-crash).

Answer (score 6):

I meet this problem last week, and i make a supplement. If the above method does not work for you, you can try the following two methods:

1. Remove your application from the simulator, and clean your project, run it again.
2. Reset Content And Setting your simulator, clean and run your project.

I hope this can help someone.

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar issue for a react native project which all of a sudden stopped working on all Xcode simulators.

We tried everything from deleting/resetting the simulators, deleting Derived data and downloading Xcode again, however nothing worked.

The only thing that worked was to create a new provisioning profile as I read at some other places also but didn't think would resolve this, however it did!

Also, if the issue comes up again after changing the profile, try with a different simulator the one which has not been used before(if needed download new simulators for different OS). Somehow the simulators become "corrupt" and gives the same issue even after resetting/erasing.